# Pop Up Edit Form for a grid: how can I know which is the currently selected row

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Grid which has edit set to Popup.

In my grid model, I have defined a field level validation for uniqueness like below. How can I know which is the currently select row so I can avoid comparing my field value with the same row's value?

```
 model: {  
        id: "id",
        fields: {
            id: {
                nullable: false,
                editable: false,
                hidden : true
            },
            "timeStamp": {
                type: "date",
                validation: { // validation rules
                    required: true, // the field is required
                    unique: function (input) {
                            if (!input.is("[name=timeStamp]")) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        input.attr("data-unique-msg", '${msg.UNIQUE_TIME}'  );
                             var data = grid.dataSource.data();
                            //HOW CAN I KNOW WHICH ROW Is currently selected?
```

Answer (score 3):

I am also working with custom validators on a Kendo Grid Popup Window.  I used the following code to obtain the model:

```
var m = $(input).closest('.k-popup-edit-form').data('kendoEditable').options.model;
```

I prefer this mechanism because I don't have refer to the grid object, making the code more portable from page to page.

Comment: Both answers are working - I prefer yours due to the portability.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little tricky solution but it should work... Each record in a DataSource has a Unique Id assigned by Kendo UI. These `uid`, for `popup` editing is used in the window in such a way that Kendo UI can easily identify the record being edited without having to save the state. You should do the same.

Your function just need to do:

```
var uid = $(input).closest(".k-popup-edit-form").data("uid");
var item = grid.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
```

Now, `item` contains all the fields of the record being edited.